# Time for another Add-A-Gram!

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

An Add-A-Gram takes a word, adds a letter, and then shuffles the letters to make a new word (I guess you can call this an Add-A-Gram's Add-A-Grammar). In this game, I will define an Add-A-Gram chain, and *a solution should contain the complete list of words in the chain*.

For example, if I provided this definition: **depend** *inside* **a race** *inside* **a counselor**

The answer would be: rely -> relay -> lawyer

Here is the definition for this Add-A-Gram chain:

**a constant** *inside* **the supertonic** *inside* **days of yore** *inside* **insightful one** *inside* **a dwarf wanderer** *inside* **Q.T.** *inside* **parrots** *inside* **arcane** *inside* **humour** *inside* **operations** *inside* **a treater** *inside* **a return** *inside* **hot potatoes** *inside* **nurseries**

For those of you who worked on my first Add-A-Gram, n.b. I made an attempt to use less obscure words and put more work into the clues.

As I am just developing this puzzle type, I welcome your continued feedback!

Happy Add-A-Gramming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution

> 1. constant = *e*
>  2. supertonic = *re*
>  3. days of yore = *ere*
>  4. insightful one = *seer*
>  5. dwarf wanderer = *[Ceres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet))*
>  6. QT = *secret*
>  7. parrots = *recites*
>  8. arcane = *esoteric*
>  9. humour = *secretion*
>  10. operations = *resections*
>  11. treater = *intercessor*
>  12. return = *retrocession*
>  13. hot potatoes = *controversies*
>  14. nurseries = *conservatories*

Comment: I hope you're enjoying this puzzle! +1 for the progress made so far.

Comment: Well I have to say, I am very impressed! :)

Comment: Nice!! +1 Well done :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson This was fun.  May I create my own?

Comment: Please do! It would be fun to be on the solving side!! :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson Just a tip, some of these were a little vague which forced us to move in an incorrect direction. Like, the QT and the preposition one. A couple others were the dwarf and parrots. :) Make a precise one next time ;) +1 already for both - the question and the answer :)

Comment: @Techidiot thanks for the advice! I knew the preposition one was too vague almost right away. And I can see where the others had too many options. I don't think red herrings belong in this format. I will be as precise as possible next time! :)

Comment: Okay, [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47867/another-another-add-a-gram) is my attempt at designing this puzzle.