# Another another Add-A-Gram

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

This is based on the [Add-A-Gram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/its-time-to-play-add-a-gram) puzzles by [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson). You need to find a chain of words, such that each next word is an anagram of the previous word plus an additional letter.

Example: **a doctor** inside **a rejection** inside **an elector**; the solution is "vet", "veto", "voter".

Here is the chain for you to solve:

a **root** inside a **symbol** inside a **division** inside a **landing** inside **dullness** inside **brightness** inside a **counter** inside a **liar** inside a **lie** inside **commanders** inside **substitutes** inside **instruments**.

Each one is a single word. That's 12 different words in total. Can you identify them?

Comment: Haha this is fun to see from the other side! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go -

> a root — *i*   ($i=\sqrt{-1}$)
>  a symbol — *pi*
>  a division — *rip*
>  a landing — *pier*
>  dullness — *tripe*
>  brightness — *esprit*
>  a counter — *riposte*
>  a liar — *imposter*
>  a lie — *misreport*
>  commanders — *imperators*
>  substitutes — *temporaries*
>  instruments — *polarimeters* or *vaporimeters*

Comment: Haha you literally beat me at my own game! :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson Lol! well played.

Comment: It's both rewarding and humbling to create a puzzle type and then get beaten on said puzzle type within 24 hours! :D

Comment: @Rubio You are right that "pie" is not right.

Comment: @Rubio You may want to change that 'pie' part to either 'pri' (primera division) or 'rpi', also known as rensselaer polytechnic institutes, that has its own sport clubs and divisions (e.g. ice hockey). Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rensselaer_Polytechnic_Institute

Comment: @Rubio No, none of the entries are abbreviations or acronyms. The solutions need to be *words*.